# Assertion failed while using imwrite OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, c++17

When running this code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<cv::Mat> imgs(argc - 1);
    for (auto i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[i]);
        cv::Mat dst;
        cv::GaussianBlur(img, dst, cv::Size(3, 3), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
        cv::Sobel(dst, dst, -1, 1, 1);
        imgs.push_back(dst);
    }

    for (auto i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        string filename(argv[i]);
        filename[0] = toupper(filename[0]);
        filename.end()[-5] = 'a';
        cv::imwrite(filename, imgs[i]);
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.3.0)
>   /tmp/opencv-20200408-5080-l00ytm/opencv-4.3.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:738:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<cv::Mat> imgs(argc - 1);
```

should be

```
vector<cv::Mat> imgs;
```

You don't create the vector at the required size and then use `push_back`.

Either create the vector at zero size and use `push_back` to add items to it, or create the vector at the required size and use subscripting to assign items to it.

Also as Gerardo Zinno said, you have an off by one error in your final for loop.

```
cv::imwrite(filename, imgs[i]);
```

should be

```
cv::imwrite(filename, imgs[i-1]);
```

Comment: There's also a problem with indices in the last function. The array imgs should be accessed starting from 0, not 1.

Comment: Yes, I agree, `cv::imwrite(filename, imgs[i]);` should be `cv::imwrite(filename, imgs[i-1]);`